# PHP send email with plain text, html message and attachments

Tags: php

can someone tell me how to send an email in PHP with plain text, HTML message and attachments, please

with the php function `mail()`.

I don't find a working solution for that.

But for example with PHPMAiler, it is possible, but in my case I don't want to use it, I want to have it without dependency and I want to understand how it works.

thank you very much

I tried some code from Google and on my own.

the attachments and plaintext is sent, but the HTML message not (depends on the order of what is declared last plain text or HTML)

I want to see the plaintext (email client is set to: plain text view), the HTML (email client is set to: html view) and the attachments.

Code

```
$to = 'xyz@xyz.com';
$subject = 'my test subject';

$htmlMessage = 'this <i>is</i> html';
$plaintextMessage = 'this is plain text';

$attachments = [
    0 => [
        'path' => 'download/',
        'file' => 'test1.pdf'
    ],
    1 => [
        'path' => 'download/',
        'file' => 'test2.pdf'
    ],
];

# Setup mime boundary
$mimeBoundary = md5((string) time());
$mimeBoundaryMixed = $mimeBoundary . '_mixed';
$mimeBoundaryAlternative = $mimeBoundary . '_alternative';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$mimeBoundaryMixed\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";

$body  = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";

$body .= "--$mimeBoundaryMixed\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mimeBoundaryAlternative\"\n";

$body .= "--$mimeBoundaryAlternative\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=UTF-8\"\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body .= $plaintextMessage;
$body .= "\n\n";

# HTML version
if ($htmlMessage !== null) {
    $body .= "--$mimeBoundaryAlternative\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body .= $htmlMessage;
    $body .= "\n\n";
}
$body .= "--$mimeBoundaryAlternative--\n";

#Attachments
if (count($attachments) > 0) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment){
        if ($attachment['path'] !== '' && $attachment['file'] !== '') {
            $file_size = filesize($attachment['path'] .  $attachment['file']);
            $handle = fopen($attachment['path'] . $attachment['file'], "r");
            $fileContent = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $fileContent = chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContent));

            $body .= "--$mimeBoundaryMixed\n";
            $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $attachment['file'] . "\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $attachment['file'] . "\"\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= $fileContent."\r\n\r\n";
        }
    }
}

# End email
$body .= "--$mimeBoundaryMixed--\n";
```

`mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);`
with this code, I get an email with htmltext (htmltext view in the client) and 2 attachements. only the plaintext (plaintext view in the client) does not work; it also shows the HTML instead of the plaintext. when I change the position from the plaintext and the htmltext, I get only the plaintext (and no htmltext)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is there any good reason to write such huge and error prone code by hand and not use any library that takes all these difficult parts from you?

Comment: Use PHPMailer instead of manually building headers and body

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting here? What do you think the result should be if you both set the HTML and the plaintext message?

Comment: @DarkBee it's [not unusual to do that](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+with+both+html+and+plain+text). The receiving mail client can pick which version to use, depending on its display capabilities.

Comment: @ADyson - I know (and it's [even good practice](https://downloads.intercomcdn.com/i/o/278560639/f219beb3eb56a725ee4b5f83/image.png) to set both), but isn't that the question at hand? "*get an email with htmltext and 2 attachements. only the plaintext does not work. when I change the position from the plaintext and the htmltext, I get only the plaintext (and no htmltext)*". OP is expecting to both see the plaintext as the HTML, but it's up to the (e-mail)client to decide which to show

Comment: @DarkBee Ah yes, that is perhaps the misunderstanding here. Thanks

Comment: @Huberto you need to test this with two different email clients...one which is configured to show emails as HTML (if available in the email), and another configured to show emails as plain-text. You cannot expect both versions to show up at the same time. I would expect that actually both versions are probably sent (you should be able to check the original source code of the mail, on most clients) but - as above - the mail client decides which one to actually display.

Comment: Would be great to see the output of this command to check what are you using for sending emails! 
`php -i | grep mail`

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your answers. I use thunderbird, there you can switch to HTML view or Plaintext view. But in my case this does not work, it only shows the HTML text in both cases. When I do the same with PHPMailer, it works, it shows the html in the html view and the plaintext in the plaintext view.

Comment: @DarkBee please see my answer to ADyson

Comment: Ok. So did you check the actual source code of the email which was delivered to thunderbird? I believe it should be able to show you the raw mail content. Then you can see if any of the content you thought you had sent is missing, or if it's just ignoring it for some reason.

Comment: @FedeCaceres thanks, the command shows:
 
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Even in Thunderbird, you can inspect the raw mail content to check whether the HTML part is really not attached